# Cannot evaluate HTML elements in Rubymine using ruby 2.3.0

Tags: ruby, watir, rubymine

I'm working on a web automation project, written by Cucumber and Watir framework.

Yesterday I updated my Ruby from 2.2.0 to 2.3.0 then I cannot debug html elements in Rubymine IDE anymore

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPJsb.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCUcE.png

These are some info, please tell me if you need more info

Rubymine 7.1.5
watir-webdriver (0.9.1)
page-object (1.2.0)
ruby-debug-ide (tried 0.4.32 and 0.6.0)
debase (0.2.1)

(*) I tried Rubymine 2016 or ruby 2.3.1 but does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have isolated this problem to be a compatibility issue with Ruby 2.3.1 and the combination of RubyMine with the ruby-debug-ide gem.

You can vote to have this issue addressed by JetBrains here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-18301

Also, you can track the issue filed against the ruby-debug-ide gem here:
https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide/issues/80

We need upvotes with Jetbrains so that they can prioritize this issue. A lot of people have just quit using RubyMine and have switched to using pry for debugging. I really love the RubyMine IDE, which is why I am trying to get this issue some visibility.